# Is there an Azure resource that can run a Macro in an excel document?

Tags: excel, vba, azure, azure-logic-apps

I have some excel reports, with Macros within them.
The Macros connect to an SQL Server, transforms some SQL data, loads the results into an excel table, and refreshes the pivots and charts contained within the Excel spreadsheet.
Currently I manually click on Run Marco in the Excel spreadsheet.
Could an Azure Logic App, or another Azure Resource, Run the Macro instead for me?

Comment: No but you might want to consider migrating this to Power BI

Comment: As an extra question; Can Power BI send data/visualisations out in an e-mail?

Comment: Yes. They're called subscriptions. But there is possibly a cost involved (a Pro licence). What is your reasoning for including cloud in your required solution? (i.e. Azure Functions). Is your primary objective to automate report generation including emailing?

Comment: Sounds like Power BI will be perfect.  As Power BI isn't ready for us yet, I was hoping for a short-term solution.  I noticed that Azure Logic Apps can run SQL Stored Procedures so I was hoping they could run Excel Macros too.  Do you have any alternative suggestions that could me automate the report generation?

Comment: Excel is not an unattended batch tool. There's too many things that can go wrong. You can use a library like EPPlus to automate excel to a certain extent. Basically there are many tools you can use to render SQL data and email it but none of these would be short term solutions. There are a lot of systems that have been built in Excel VBA that come to a dead end beacuse it be automated in an unattended fashion

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there appears to be no way to do this so I have raised a suggestion to Azure - please visit the link below and vote if you would like to connect Azure to Excel Macros....
[Microsoft Azure Suggestions Link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/40817116-have-an-azure-logic-app-action-to-execute-run-an-e)